# Use of Little-oh(o) and Little Omega(ω)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

What is the use/purpose of little-oh and little Omega notations ?

Although I perfectly understand the notations themselves and what they represent.
I have not seen a single book or algorithm that use them in any of the calculations  so I can't help but wonder why were they even created if they are not used.

Comment: If you believe [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), *"Little-o notation is common in mathematics but rarer in computer science."* So it might be better to [ask the mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/) why they use it.

Comment: I understand that little Oh means strictly increasing and little Omega means strictly decreasing but what is their use in computer science time -complexity calculations ?

Comment: @NeoR Where does this information come from? The two have nothing to do with whether a function is increasing or decreasing

Comment: Little-oh is used quite extensively in compsci. I'm currently working on succinct data structures, where it is very common to bound remainder terms using little-oh. Example: A binary tree of n nodes can be represented using 2n + o(n) bits. Similarly, you can support "rank" on an n-bit vector using a support data structure of size o(n)

Comment: @NiklasB. Firstly nice example maybe you can post it in the answers and I got that information from a book although I can't remember which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't help but wonder why were they even created if they are not used.

I don't think that's correct (although I can't right now find links to all of the claims below).

For one, these notations are directly used in math terms that come up in analysis of algorithms.

- For example, in [Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521835402) , in the chapter dealing with the [probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method), there are often statements about some choice being made with probability *1 - o(1)* (meaning that as the input size increases, it becomes increasingly rare not to choose something).
- When discussing [the sum of the harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence) (which comes up, e.g., in the analysis of quicksort), the term is sometimes given as *ln(k) + α + o(1)*.

I've often seen them come up in discussions:

- [More exact analysis of heapsort variations](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/papers/sorting.pdf) sometimes use terms like *2n log(n) (1 - o(1))* and *n log(n) (1 + o(1))* (the paper linked here doesn't though).
- When there's a practical lower bound on some problem (either through proof or because a better solution doesn't exist), things similar to "you can't do this in *f(n)*, because it is *o(g(n))*" (equivalently, "because *g(n)* is *ω(f(n))*"). (For example: "you can't sort this in time *n*, because *n log(n)* is *ω(n)*".) This could be said through limits or through combinations of *O* and not *Θ*, but it would be tedious.